# Cleaner looking way to do case in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to do a linq statement, with 3 part case. The way i have it seems super ugly, and im hopeing someone will reveal a cleaner way to do this. Its ugly so im going to break it into parts

To explain this a little i join these two tables like this, to perform a left join

```
 from ccc in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings                        
 join cl in currentLogs 
 on ccc.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID equals 
 cl.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID into final
```

I then filter out the result by storefrontID

```
 where f.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.Category.StorefrontID == StorefrontID
```

I then group then order

```
 group f by new {f.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.Category.CategoryID} into t1
 orderby t1.Key.CategoryID
```

Finally i tried to output the results into a structure, but take a look at status

```
select new 
CategoryStruct { 
    CategoryName =t1.Max(x=>x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.Category.Name) , 
    Status = t1.Any(n=>n.Response==null)?99:t1.Any(n=>n.Response==0)?0:-1, 
             AverageResponseTime = (int)t1.Average(x => x.CaptureTime), 
    categoryId = t1.Key.CategoryID 
});
```

I use the terator operator and it looks terrible. Im trying to say **if response is null(because of the join) let status be 0, else if response is 0, let status be 0, else let status be -1.** I dont think putting an if statement would make it look any better. Also performance is a concern, there will be about 50k rows, but only about 20 categoryStructs after the grouping is performed.

Comment: When you have working code and only seek improvements, please post the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault dont suppose theres a easy transfer button?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can easily copy-paste the text, CR is also a StackExchange website so the question syntax/symbols are the same.

Comment: To my eyes, this code is fairly concise and readable.  The only thing I might do is add some spaces in there to improve formatting.

Comment: If query performance is a concern, I would reconsider if LINQ is the answer. There's nothing wrong with a carefully crafted SQL stored procedure or view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a little cleaner by adding two `let` variables before your `select` and use those variables in your ternary operators. like this:

```
...
let anyNullResponses = t1.Any(n=>n.Response==null)
let anyZeroResponses = t1.Any(n=>n.Response==0)
select new {
...
   Status = anyNullResponses ? 99 :
            anyZeroResponses  ? 0 : -1, 
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much you can do except to play with the spacing a little to make it easier to read. Here's one example of how you might do that.

```
select new 
CategoryStruct { 
    CategoryName =t1.Max(x=>x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMapping.Category.Name) , 
    Status = t1.Any(n=>n.Response==null) ? 99 :
             t1.Any(n=>n.Response==0) ? 0 : 
             -1, 
    AverageResponseTime = (int)t1.Average(x => x.CaptureTime), 
    categoryId = t1.Key.CategoryID 
});
```